# No value for float values form JSON object

Tags: android, json

Edit: I was getting the floats from the wrong object - my bad. Having same problem with the timestamp though - Int cannot be converted to JSONObject

I am getting the city and country fine from openweathermap, but the app crashes on the float values. I am very new to android and is my first time using JSON so any help would be appreciated.
I am reading in a 7 day forecast. This is my WeatherParser class, which is passed a city location from a text view:

```
    JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(data);
    JSONObject city = jObj.getJSONObject("city");

    Location loc = new Location();
    loc.setCity(getString("name", city));
    loc.setCountry(getString("country", city));

    weather.setLocation(loc);

    JSONArray jArr = jObj.getJSONArray("list");
    for (int i = 0; i < jArr.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject dailyForecast = jArr.getJSONObject(i);
        JSONObject time = dailyForecast.getJSONObject("dt");
        JSONObject temp = dailyForecast.getJSONObject("temp");
        JSONObject dayTemp = temp.getJSONObject("day");
        JSONObject max = temp.getJSONObject("max");
        JSONObject min = temp.getJSONObject("min");

        DailyForecast df = new DailyForecast();
        long unixSeconds = (long) getLong("dt", time);
        Date date = new Date(unixSeconds*1000L); // *1000 is to convert minutes to milliseconds
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z", Locale.US);
        String formattedDate = sdf.format(date);
        df.setDay(formattedDate);
        df.setTemp(getFloat("day", dayTemp));
        df.setMax(getFloat("max", max));
        df.setMin(getFloat("min", min));

        JSONArray jAr = dailyForecast.getJSONArray("weather");
        if(jAr.length() > 2) {
             JSONObject desc = jAr.getJSONObject(2);   //get the 3rd item
             df.setDesc(getString("description", desc));
        }

        weeksForecast[i] = df;
    }
    weather.fillForecast(weeksForecast);
    return weather;
}

private static String getString(String tagName, JSONObject jObj)
        throws JSONException {
    return jObj.getString(tagName);
}
private static float getFloat(String tagName, JSONObject jObj)
        throws JSONException {
    return (float) jObj.getDouble(tagName);
}
private static float getLong(String tagName, JSONObject jObj)
        throws JSONException {
    return (long) jObj.getDouble(tagName);
}

}
```

10-24 19:48:03.728: D/gralloc_goldfish(954): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
10-24 19:48:12.398: D/dalvikvm(954): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 163K, 9% free 2855K/3136K, paused 36ms, total 36ms
10-24 19:48:12.448: W/System.err(954): org.json.JSONException: Value 12.74 at day of type java.lang.Double cannot be converted to JSONObject
10-24 19:48:12.448: W/System.err(954):  at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:100)
10-24 19:48:12.448: W/System.err(954):  at org.json.JSONObject.getJSONObject(JSONObject.java:577)
10-24 19:48:12.448: W/System.err(954):  at com.meaProject.yawa.WeatherParser.getWeather(WeatherParser.java:31)
10-24 19:48:12.448: W/System.err(954):  at com.meaProject.yawa.MainActivity$JSONWeatherTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:58)
10-24 19:48:12.458: W/System.err(954):  at com.meaProject.yawa.MainActivity$JSONWeatherTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
10-24 19:48:12.458: W/System.err(954):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
10-24 19:48:12.458: W/System.err(954):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
10-24 19:48:12.458: W/System.err(954):  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
10-24 19:48:12.458: W/System.err(954):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
10-24 19:48:12.458: W/System.err(954):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
10-24 19:48:12.468: W/System.err(954):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)

Comment: Please post stack trace from logcat and also the line number in your code it points to.

Comment: show object you try to parse.